# Remove "required field" validation in street[0] input Magento 2.3.5

Tags: magento2, magento2.3.5

I need to separate the street field into two inputs (street and number), but send them as the same field to the database.

One solution was to create these inputs, concatenate their value with Javascript and insert it into the input street [0]. This works quite well, but at the time of going to the billing section I can't move forward because it indicates that the field is empty, even when I insert a value with javascript.

how can i disable this validation?

**It is not an option to use more street lines. I already use the 4 available**

I know this seems strange, but because we migrate from M1 to M2 we need it in that way